# Getting a category name from only a specific group in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories

I'm new to wordpress and have a quick question about showing a post's category names. I have two main categories

Games

- free cell
- solitaire
- classic games

  -- pong

  -- ms. pacman

Featured Games

etcetera. So that I can make a post and tag what game it is from (note that there are three tiers here). If my post was a screen grab of ms. pacman, i would choose the Games > Classic Games > Ms. Pacman category. I might also want this awesome image in my home page featured slider, so I might choose Featured Games as well.

However!!! When I get to the post detail page, i just want to spit out CATEGORY: Ms. Pacman. I don't want Games / Classic Games or Featured Games.

So now, I have

```
<?php the_category(', ', 'single');?>
```

To show only the child element, but it is still showing all three levels as well as the Featured categories. I think I need to exclude that "featured category" id from the query but don't know how. Here's my specific code:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ):?>
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
    <div class="category">CATEGORY: <?php the_category(', ', 'single');?></div>
  <?php endwhile;?>    
<?php endif;?>
```

I don't know how to do custom queries or what to change or where to change it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there aren't any filters that will easily produce what you're looking for, but it should be possible to put something together using the source code of get_the_category_list which you can find here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-includes/category-template.php#L0

Like this, change the markup as you please:

```
$categories = get_the_category( false );
foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks Calle. I'm very new to Wordpress and have already run into an amazing number of brick walls of functionality I'm just shocked isn't possible!!

Comment: I ended up with something like this: <?php      foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
if ($category->category_parent == '201'){      echo "CATEGORY: ".$category->cat_name ."<br/>";
}
}
?>

Comment: Looks to me like you want to know if the post is in a certain category and if it is, then write the name of that category. It could be done without the loop, like <?php echo has_category('201') ? 'Category: category name' : ''; ?> (I think, didn't check it)

Comment: I had to throw in that loop to handle inserting singular code and commas, but if there was only one category for each post, your solution would be perfect.Thanks!